# mp3/ogg to Text

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Имеется ссылка на ogg/mp3 файл.
Требуется перевести содержание аудиофайла в текст.

Получилось осуществить это с помощью SpeechRecognition, но данная бибилотека поддерживает только wav и несколько других типов аудиофайлов. Поэтому мне пришлось сначала конвертировать mp3 в wav, а это занимает слишком много времени.

Существуют ли более быстрые способы конвертировать из аудио в текст?

Comment: Какого вида текст Вы хотите получить? просто байты по порядку?

Comment: В виде обычной строки 'str'

Comment: Я немного не об этом. Что должна содержать эта строка?

Comment: Строка должна содержать текст из аудиофайла, то есть голос человека в текстовом виде

Comment: сначала конвертировать mp3 в wav

Comment: Это вы тоже на Python делали?

Comment: @PillTommy Уж не думаете ли Вы, что аудиозапись в каком-то виде содержит сказанный на ней текст?

Comment: конвертировать запись в вав занимает совсем немного времени. можно гнать в пайп.. может лучше задать вопрос подругому?

Comment: @eri Мне приходится по ссылке записывать в mp3 файл, потом из mp3 файла в новый wav файл, а потом уже обрабатывать. Обработка 5-ти секундного файла таким способом занимает 1 секунду, что в моём случае слишком много.

Comment: @PillTommy зачем в файл сохранять?

Comment: @eri Чтобы дальше экспортировать в wav

Comment: Пайпов нет в вашей операционной системе?) ссылку можно получить на пример файла? Они все по пять секунд? Простой декодер mp3 работает со скоростью 40 х

Comment: @eri Аудио любой длительности. Пример можете посмотреть в любом голосовом сообщении ВКонтакте